# My ubuntu 15.04 file system is not writable

Tags: boot, permissions, lightdm, ssd, 15.04

The problem started when my lightdm config got messed up and would only boot to a black screen with a cursor. In an attempt to fix this I booted up into recovery mode, dropped into the shell and tried to manually edit the config files.

The real problem is that whenever I open a config file, or try to change anything on the disk I get the error that I do not have permission or the disk is a read only file system.

My windows 8 partition on the same SSD works fine so I do not believe it is a hardware issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read Only is the state that recovery mode boots into intentionally.  What you need to do is remount the root partition with read-write privileges.

This will remount the drive as readable and writable.  Execute this in the recovery console:

```
mount -rw -o remount /
```